# How to get access to Fuel Flap on VW Polo?

Tags: fuel-system, vw, locks, polo, central-locking

My Fuel Flap wont unlock... it has been playing up for a few months but now it wont open at all.

I need to put fuel in my car but cannot unlock the Fuel Flap, I have tried unlocking and locking via the Car key and unlocking using the lock switch on drivers side but still not realising the flap.

Is there any way to manually get this open on my Volkswagen Polo Match (62 Model) as I need to put Fuel in ASAP?

& Any ideas on how much it can cost to get this repaired?

Thanks, Holly

Comment: Try have someone push or ever so slightly pull on the flap as you unlock the car... It might take a few attempts...

Comment: In an old Jetta I had, the fuel flap lock could be accessed by pulling off the side of the trunk liner.  It was a tight fit, but maybe enough if it failed.  You don't have a trunk, but removing an interior trim panel could give you access to it (I've never worked on a Polo).

Answer (score 1):

The flap lock mechanism is at least in my  Polo a simple pneumatic pump.
Remove the side of the trunk liner behind the fuel flap.
It should be an pneumatic pump there with an air hose to the lock (the lock is a pin which is driven thru a wedge on the flap's inside.)